# Are there some additions that a Turing machine cannot perform

Tags: turing-machines, computability

The total number of Turing machines is the cardinality of the set of natural numbers. Now consider the following functions

- f1(x) = x + 1
- f2(x) = x + 2
- f3(x) = x + 3
- and so on

Since the total number of these functions is also the same as the cardinality of the set of natural numbers, each of these functions can be assigned to one Turing machine.

Therefore either there must be no Turing machines left to do other computations or they can do other computations at the expense of not being able to do some of these.

What am I missing here.
Thank you.

Comment: As Nathaniel indicates in his answer, this doesn’t mean that other Turing machines don’t exist. For instance, consider the Turing machine which generates strings in the language $L = \{a^nb^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ and add it to the collection you created above. Then the cardinality is $|\mathbb{N}| + 1 = \aleph_0 + 1 = \aleph_0$.

Answer (score 3):

The cardinality of even natural numbers is the same as the cardinality of natural numbers.

That does not mean that odd natural numbers do not exist.